# Converte uma consulta SQL em Consulta no Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Fiz esse pergunta em um outro fórum, mas o conteúdo da discussão seguiu outro caminho por isso resolvi abri esse tópico. Sem fugir do assunto, como faço para realizar essa consulta SQL:

```
select p.RA, p.Nome, p.Modulo, a.Descricao
from inscricao as i, participante as p, Atividade as a 
where i.ParticipanteId = p.ParticipanteId and 
   i.AtividadeId = a.AtividadeId order by p.Modulo
```

em uma consulta usando o Entity?

Comment: Coloque as entidades na pergunta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente fazer da seguinte forma.

```
var query = (from i in dbContext.inscricao
                     join p in dbContext.participante on i.ParticipanteId equals p.ParticipanteId
                     join a in dbContext.Atividade on p.AtividadeId equals a.AtividadeId
                     where i.periodo == ViewModel.periodo && i.data == ViewModel.data.
                     select new {
                         RA = p.RA,
                         Nome = p.Nome,
                         Modulo = p.Modulo,
                         Descricao = a.Descricao
                     })
                     .OrderBy(x => x.Modulo);
```

Comment: Obrigado Marconcilio, e agora estou a apanhando da sintaxe para incluir nessa mesma consulta mais duas condições: Na tabela de inscrições preciso verificar se os campo periodo == ViewModel.periodo e data == ViewModel.data.

Comment: alterei a query